# sum the number of seconds between dates of the same stationid sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

im trying to make a query that gets the difference between 2 (consecutive) dates as long as the stationid is the same, then subtract 112 seconds then take the next 2 dates with the same stationid and do the same, add this new number to the previous result and so on for all stationid available. This is an example of the table I got: (in this example there are only two different stationid, but I have above 20 more).

```
ID  DateAndTime              StationId
3   2014-08-20 20:07:17.000 GDLPCTE053
4   2014-08-20 20:08:50.000 GDLPCACL035
5   2014-08-20 20:10:42.000 GDLPCTE053
6   2014-08-20 20:10:55.000 GDLPCACL035
7   2014-08-20 20:12:57.000 GDLPCACL035
8   2014-08-20 20:14:58.000 GDLPCTE053
9   2014-08-20 20:17:20.000 GDLPCTE053
10  2014-08-20 20:16:31.000 GDLPCACL035
11  2014-08-20 20:19:33.000 GDLPCTE053
12  2014-08-20 20:19:46.000 GDLPCACL035
13  2014-08-20 20:23:19.000 GDLPCTE053
14  2014-08-20 20:23:14.000 GDLPCACL035
15  2014-08-20 20:26:08.000 GDLPCTE053
16  2014-08-20 20:25:10.000 GDLPCACL035
```

for instance, the first stationID is `GDLPCACL053` so I want to get the difference between `2014-08-20 20:07:17.000` and `2014-08-20 20:10:42.000` (which is the next with the same stationid (that's 205 seconds) minus 112 (this is a constant) we get 93.
Then I want to sum this 93 to the result of this same operation for the next date, so it ill be the diff between `2014-08-20 20:10:42.000` and `2014-08-20 20:14:58.000` get the seconds minus 112 plus the original 93 and so on, so by the end i just get the stationsid and the number of seconds that are being wasted (the sum of this) for a period of time.

I'm well aware that my description is very very poor, but I'm in a hurry and my English is pretty bad.

I thank anyone in advance for your time and trying to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross apply like this:

```
declare @T table (ID int, DateAndTime datetime, StationID varchar(50))
insert into @T (ID, DateAndTime, StationID) values
('3', '2014-08-20 20:07:17.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('4', '2014-08-20 20:08:50.000', 'GDLPCACL035'),
('5', '2014-08-20 20:10:42.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('6', '2014-08-20 20:10:55.000', 'GDLPCACL035'),
('7', '2014-08-20 20:12:57.000', 'GDLPCACL035'),
('8', '2014-08-20 20:14:58.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('9', '2014-08-20 20:17:20.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('10', '2014-08-20 20:16:31.000', 'GDLPCACL035'),
('11', '2014-08-20 20:19:33.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('12', '2014-08-20 20:19:46.000', 'GDLPCACL035'),
('13', '2014-08-20 20:23:19.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('14', '2014-08-20 20:23:14.000', 'GDLPCACL035'),
('15', '2014-08-20 20:26:08.000', 'GDLPCTE053'),
('16', '2014-08-20 20:25:10.000', 'GDLPCACL035')


select 
    t1.StationID,   
    sum(datediff(s, t2.DateAndTime, t1.DateAndTime) - 112)
from @T as t1
cross apply
(
    select top 1 t2.DateAndTime
    from @T as t2
    where
        t1.StationID = t2.StationID and
        t2.DateAndTime < t1.DateAndTime
    order by t2.DateAndTime desc
) as t2
group by t1.StationID
```

Results:

```
GDLPCACL035 308
GDLPCTE053  459
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler in SQL Server 2012+ where you can take advantage of [**`lag()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and other window functions:

```
select id, dateandtime, stationid
  , wasted_seconds  = sum(datediff(second,prev,dateandtime)-112) 
      over (partition by stationid order by dateandtime)
from (
  select *
    , prev = lag(dateandtime) over (partition by stationid order by dateandtime)
  from t
  ) sub
order by stationid, dateandtime
```

In SQL Server 2008 you can use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) in place of those window functions like so:

```
;with cte as (
select t.*
  , p.prev
  , wasted_seconds = datediff(second, p.prev, t.dateandtime)-112
from t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 prev = i.dateandtime
    from t as i
    where i.stationid = t.stationid
      and i.dateandtime < t.dateandtime
    order by i.dateandtime desc
  ) p
)
select 
    id
  , dateandtime
  , stationid
  , wasted_seconds = x.wasted_seconds
from cte
  cross apply (
    select wasted_seconds = sum(i.wasted_seconds)
    from cte i
    where i.stationid = cte.stationid
      and i.dateandtime <= cte.dateandtime
    ) x
order by stationid, dateandtime
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NNQ6563

returns:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| id |     dateandtime     |  stationid  | wasted_seconds |
+----+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
|  4 | 2014-08-20 20:08:50 | gdlpcacl035 | NULL           |
|  6 | 2014-08-20 20:10:55 | gdlpcacl035 | 13             |
|  7 | 2014-08-20 20:12:57 | gdlpcacl035 | 23             |
| 10 | 2014-08-20 20:16:31 | gdlpcacl035 | 125            |
| 12 | 2014-08-20 20:19:46 | gdlpcacl035 | 208            |
| 14 | 2014-08-20 20:23:14 | gdlpcacl035 | 304            |
| 16 | 2014-08-20 20:25:10 | gdlpcacl035 | 308            |
|  3 | 2014-08-20 20:07:17 | gdlpcte053  | NULL           |
|  5 | 2014-08-20 20:10:42 | gdlpcte053  | 93             |
|  8 | 2014-08-20 20:14:58 | gdlpcte053  | 237            |
|  9 | 2014-08-20 20:17:20 | gdlpcte053  | 267            |
| 11 | 2014-08-20 20:19:33 | gdlpcte053  | 288            |
| 13 | 2014-08-20 20:23:19 | gdlpcte053  | 402            |
| 15 | 2014-08-20 20:26:08 | gdlpcte053  | 459            |
+----+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
```